# Is there a standard way to model the API requests from each screen?

Tags: android, ios, sequence-diagram

To elaborate, I am working on an app with more than 50 screens.
Each screen has to make multiple different API calls to get the data from backend.
User can act on this data in any of the screens and then this will also result in a request to a backend API.

Is there a standard way to model this API to screen mapping?
I was looking at UML sequence diagrams but it seems too complicated for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Android Architecture guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture) and [Modularization guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/modularization/patterns#feature-modules) you can divide your screens and APIs in UI and Data layers.

ones that is done you can create diagrams like this:

[image]